# Change date list in quick launch area to date+subject (SP2010)

Tags: 2010, meeting-workspace

We have created a Meeting Workspace on our site and we want to collect all the meetings in this workspace (which is working just fine). But: The list of meetings in the workspace is only showing the date in the quick launch area, even if there is more than one meeting for a day. It would be great if this could somehow be customized to include also the subject ... or the first few letters of the subject plus ellipses or similar.

Is this possible with the web interface and/or SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Without going too deep into manipulating master pages etc, you could create a web part page,  add a list view or data view web part in the left hand column and arrange the other content as desired. Set that as the home page and most users will be happy most of the time.

With a DVWP you can concatenate fields and show them in one column.

If you need the quick launch with exactly these items to show on **every** site page, then you will have to put in more effort. You can customize the master page (or rather, create a copy, customize the copy and assign it to the site).  You can hide the original quick launch div in the master page and include a DVWP or other web part in its stead.